# Shadow not showing on Androidx Cardview

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview

My layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".TurnOnLocation">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/requires_location"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/turn_on_location">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="60dp"
                android:paddingEnd="60dp"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:text="test"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/turn_on_location"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/medium_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/turn_on_location"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/requires_location"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've specified the `app:cardElevation="10dp"` which I believe is meant to render the drop shadow. However no shadow is appearing.

Any idea why?

Comment: Add `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`

Comment: Doesn't add a shadow. It also prevents me from having 0 padding horizontally: https://i.imgur.com/ab3Uo1l.png

Comment: Add `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in your manifest section.

Comment: Need margin   `android:layout_margin="5dp"`

Comment: Added both - still no shadow.

Comment: @Zorgan Did you try running the project in a device or just looking into the layout preview in the IDE ?

Comment: Yes, still no shadow.

Comment: My mistake, the shadow is there when I run on an Emulator. It was just very hard to spot. Thanks @theapache64

Comment: Sure. I've added my findings as answer to this question, so that people with this issue can save their time in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've no mistake in your source code. The shadow should be rendered correctly. You might be checking the output in your layout preview. It has some issue on rendering. Please run the app in emulator or real device.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your `AndroidManifest` this `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in `application` tag

Answer (score 2):

Use this Code, for me its works! the idea is on `app:cardUserCompatPadding="true"`

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/two_x"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add below lines into CardView tag

```
  card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
  card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
  card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

Comment: Doesn't add a shadow. It also prevents me from having 0 padding horizontally: https://i.imgur.com/ab3Uo1l.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
```

Comment: Still no shadow.

Comment: R u watching in Preview or in Emulator or Mobile device? Because it will not display any elevation in Preview. It will show only when u run application

Comment: I'm watching in my Pixel 2 Emulator